# Exposing domains using R-ArcGIS bridge (package arcgisbinding)

Tags: r, arcgis

I am using the R-ArcGIS bridge via the package arcgisbinding to access a file geodatabase in AcrGIS online.

I can bring data into R using arc.select but cannot see coded domain names.  For example, if I have coded domains Y, N for 'Yes' and 'No', then I want to be able to see Yes and No when I bring data into R, rather than the coded values Y and N.

(This is a simplified example; the coded values in my dataset are undecipherable in their coded form!)

Any ideas on how I can expose the domains?